# Binding JSON object to list in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm currently migrating an API from ASP.NET Web API to ASP.NET Core. My old API had an endpoint accepting a list as part of the body:

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Post(MyModel model)
{
    ...
}

public class MyModel
{
    public List<SomeObject> SomeObjects { get; set; }
}
```

I have some consumers of this API that was able to post the following JSON:

```
POST /post
{
    "someObjects": {}
}
```

Of course, this should have been:

```
POST /post
{
    "someObjects": []
}
```

but ASP.NET Web API model binding accepted this (setting `someObjects` to `null` I guess`).

When doing the same with ASP.NET Core, I get the following error when posting the same JSON to the API:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SomeObject]'
```

Again, I totally understand why the error is there. I need to be backwards compatible, so can anyone help? I guess I need a custom model binder or something to allow the empty object to be converted into `null` or an empty list?

Comment: Don't know the answer but maybe I can point you in the direction of setting your own `JsonSerializerSettings` https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm

Comment: _setting someObjects to null I guess`_ is this the actual current behavior?

Comment: No, the current behavior is that the request fails with the error I posted in the question.

Comment: I mean the "legacy" behavior; was the property set to null on your ASPNET WebApi?

Comment: I don't remember. The issue here isn't ASP.NET Web API though. I simply want to allow `{}` as a valid value for `List<SomeObject`. If it's `null` or an empty list in ASP.NET Core, I can handle that in the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a clean solution but you can write a custom `JsonConverter` for `List<SomeObject>` and return null or an empty list when not a list:

```cs
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter<List<SomeObject>>
{
    public override List<SomeObject> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<SomeObject> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.ToObject<List<SomeObject>>();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<SomeObject> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}

public class MyModel
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    public List<SomeObject> SomeObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have fixed the issue using your code but implemented the `ReadJson` method without exceptions. With your permission, I will update your code and mark it as the answer?

Comment: Sure, I was just too lazy to implement the best solution :)